# How can I replace a single Hash Value in Ruby by using its number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

A fairly simple question, but I don't see it anywhere on SO, and I'm a Ruby noob.

In Ruby, if I have a hash, similar to this.

```
hashOne = {'dog' => 'canine', 'cat' => 'feline', 'me' => 'rubynooby'}
```

And let's assume that I want to replace the value a couple of different ways.

**Method 1**

Let's say I want to replace the value of `me` with `rubypro`.  I've seen this done this way:

```
hashOne[:me] = "rubypro"
```

but I haven't seen a solution to replacing the value by which number it is, for example, let's assume that I always want to change the 3rd key (and assuming it starts on 1 and not 0)

**Method 2** - These don't work

```
hashOne[3] = "rubypro"
```

or

```
hashOne.values[3] = "rubypro"
```

I haven't seen any examples of this, or a question about it on SO.  Can someone point me in that direction?

The reason I was trying to work on this, is because I have a Hash, where I don't know what the key is, but I know what I want the value to be.  It's weird, but that's where I'm at.

Comment: Keep in mind that, prior to Ruby v1.9, there was no concept of hash keys having order, so if you only have the index into the array `hash.keys`, there's nothing you can do to make it work with pre-1.9 Ruby. Even if that's not a problem, I suggest you see if you can rework your code so you don't find yourself in that situation.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `hashOne[hashOne.keys[3]] = 'rubypro'`. Also I remember reading that Hashes in ruby are ordered but I'm not entirely sure. (Be careful with using indices because  they may not be ordered in other languages) I would ensure that the keys are always returned in the same order before trying to assign a key with an index.

If you really wanted to use an index, I'd recommend using an array because that's not the purpose of a key/value hash.

Comment: Ruby hashes aren't exactly sorted – they're ordered and retain insertion order.

Comment: I'm editing someone else's code, and they used a hash that never has more than one value, so ordering isn't a problem in this case, but thanks for pointing that out.  Also, not sure who downvoted.  I'll give it a try in a bit

Comment: @spike hence the words _I'm not entirely sure_. Im sorry for my verbiage but I wanted to inform the OP to be careful since hashes/lists are not always 'ordered' in every language. I'll update my answer to be more clear.

Comment: @Jeff sorry if the tone came across poorly in text! Just trying to help clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
hashOne[hashOne.keys.unshift('')[3]] = "rubypro"
```

Comment: This creates a new key-value pair: `hashOne #=> {"dog"=>"canine", "cat"=>"feline", "me"=>"rubynooby", nil=>"rubypro"}`

Comment: @sagarpandya82 good catch.. updated my answer. hope it works!!